# SharedPreferences Editor commit takes so much time

Tags: android, preferences, sharedpreferences

I try to make a configuration activity using **PreferenceActivity**...

I found some working examples like

"WiFi Advanced Configuration Editor"

and

"Wifi Config Editor Pro"

but the code I wrote waits for 10-15 seconds on the line `editor.commit()`...
it must be very simple but I cant figure out.

here is the brief code;

...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(v.getContext());
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(ClassConfig.this);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.clear();

editor.putString("key1", value1);
editor.putString("key2", value2);
editor.putBoolean("key3", value3);
    ...
    //i got nearly 35 keys here
    ...
    editor.putString("key33", value33);
editor.putBoolean("key34", value34);
editor.putBoolean("key35", value35);

    editor.commit();
```

Any ideas??

Update: one more thing. I saw these warnings in the log file

> W/BackupManagerService(1914)
>   dataChanged but no participant
>   pkg='com.android.providers.settings'
>   uid=10046

Comment: The BackupManagerService chatter has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 3):

`commit()` is executed synchronously, so you notice that it takes so much time..
Use `apply()` instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5960743/1233659

Answer (score 2):

Committing large preferences is slow - it should be done in separate thread. Consider implementing this in `AsyncTask`

Comment: check this out please.. [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-ace/source/browse/trunk/WiFiACE/src/org/marcus905/wifi/ace/WiFiACEList.java?r=11)  no threading but also no waiting... i cant get the point...

Comment: I don't know if this application runs fast enough. For explanation checkout this question (especially 4-th bullet in Brad Fitzpatrick answer): [should-accessing-sharepreferences-be-done-off-the-ui-thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371273/should-accessing-sharepreferences-be-done-off-the-ui-thread)

Comment: i will try futuretask at a convenient time.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `apply()` method which is asynchronous. See docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply())

Answer (score 0):

Where are you doing this?  OnSharedPreferenceChanged?

If you're using a PreferenceActivity, you shouldn't need to manually write your prefs, as changing widget state by the user should change the key defined in XML for the PreferenceActivity.

Comment: im doing this before using PreferenceActivity on another activity's button onclicklistener.