# Save login details(preferences) android

Tags: java, android, preferences, remember-me

I have one android app with login, logout functions. The login form contains Username and password and the login button. I want to save the username and the password when the user checks the "Remember me" check box.

My project.java file is shown below:

```
public class project extends Activity {

private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public int user_id,current_user_id;

public String access_token,username,current_username;
public boolean user_logged_in=false;
public ProgressDialog progdialog;



@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    progdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progdialog.setMessage("loading...");

    initLogin();
}

public void initLogin(){
    setContentView(R.layout.login);


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_login);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login();
        }
    });
}
public void login(){
    try{
        String login_username=(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username)).getText()).toString();
        String login_password=(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password)).getText()).toString();
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",login_username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",login_password));
        String content=postUrlContent(api_url+"landing/authenticate",nameValuePairs);
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(content);
        JSONObject respObject = jObject.getJSONObject("response");
        Boolean success=respObject.getBoolean("success");
        String message=respObject.getString("message");
        Boolean logged_in=respObject.getBoolean("logged_in");
        if(logged_in){
            user_id=respObject.getInt("user_id");
            access_token=respObject.getString("access_token");
            username=respObject.getString("username");
            current_username=username;
            current_user_id=user_id;
            user_logged_in=true;
            //initFeeds(username);
            test(0);

        }else{
            createDialog("Error",message);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use your apps shared preferences. The prefs can be accessed anytime using the key you set for these prefs

```
 static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
 static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

 if (rememberMe) { //save username and pw to prefs
      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      Editor ed = prefs.edit();
      ed.putString(KEY_USERNAME, theUsername);
      ed.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, thePW);
      ed.commit();
 }
```

To access the information, like in your onCreate method:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 String username = prefs.getString(KEY_USERNAME, "Default Value if not found");
 String password = prefs.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, ""); //return nothing if no pass saved
```

Comment: Yes you can. The same SharedPreferences are accessible to all the Activities in your app.

Comment: Note you'll want to encrypt the password. SharedPreferences is not secure (e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244318/android-sharedpreference-security).

Comment: Consider using `ed.apply()` instead of `ed.commit()` as `apply()` will run on background thread. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference) for more details