# Storing and Retrieving Values from SharedPreferences on Activity state changes

Tags: android

Basically I have a list and I need to remember the offset and load the offset value every time the Activity is restored unless the Activity completely destroyed.

```
//Inside onCreate
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
Offset = settings.getInt("TheOffset", 0);
//End onCreate

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("TheOffset", Offset);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("TheOffset", Offset);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //settings.getInt("TheOffset", 0);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("TheOffset", 0);
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @mbaird, you asked exactly what I was going to ask. ^_^

Comment: LMAO....Sorry, I haven't ate breakfast yet.

It's not working, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onPause()` will always be called before your activity is placed in the background and/or destroyed, so you do not have to save state in `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` as well.

For the state to be preserved in SharedPreferences, you need to add `editor.commit()` after writing the value. Otherwise it won't be stored. Like this:

```
super.onPause();
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("TheOffset", Offset);
editor.commit();
```

You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState

Comment: That worked thanks, I forgot the commit().  Also thanks for the tip about the states.

Comment: I recommend using apply() instead of commit(). see this stackoverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference

Answer (score 0):

You will only need to save your offset in onResume() and set it to 0 when the activity is going to be destroyed, which you can tell by using isFinishing() in onPause(), like the following:

```
protected void onPause() {
    if(isFinishing()) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("TheOffset", 0);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

...but I still have no idea what you intend to achieve.