# Difference Between commit and apply in Android SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

SharedPreferences are used to save Application data in Android.

`commit()` and `apply()` both are used to save the changes in the shared preferences.

As mentioned in Android Library:

```
public abstarct void apply():
```

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
>   storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
>   SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to
>   disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on
>   this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is
>   still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are
>   completed as well as the commit itself.

```
public abstract boolean commit ():
```

> Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the
>   SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the
>   requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the
>   SharedPreferences.

Does this mean that the changes made by `commit()` are instant as compared with `apply()`? Which one is better?

If I need to use the same shared preference value in the next immediate activity, which one should I use? As I have seen if the value of Preference is updated it is not reflected till the application is restarted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Commit()` is instantaneous but performs disk writes. If you are on the ui thread you should call `apply()` which is asynchronous.

Comment: I dint get the meaning of UI thread..!! what is tht exactly. I am novice.

Comment: UI Thread is the main thread which sets the layout and sets e.g the onClick listener.

Comment: right so time consuming operations such as disk writes would make your ui less responsive

Answer (score 15):

**apply()** - returns **void**

**apply() was added in 2.3**, it **saves without returning a boolean indicating success or failure.**

**commit()** - returns **boolean** value.

**commit()** returns true if the save works, false otherwise. `apply()` was added as the android dev team noticed that most no one took notice of the return value, so apply is faster.

You can refer to below link

**[What's the difference between commit() and apply() in Shared Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply)**