# SharedPreferences not saved in onDestroy of Service

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-sharedpreferences, android-ondestroy

Before the activity get's killed (when `OnDestroy` is called), I am saving some `int` values in `SharedPreferences`.

But what I have noticed is that it takes about a second for the values to be saved but the app doesn't wait for that before destroying the `Activity`.

Can I do some kind of `Wait` before it gets killed?

Here's my example:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("finalXPos", finalX);
    editor.putInt("finalYPos", finalY);
    editor.commit();

    super.onDestroy();
    removeView();
}
```

======================>>    EDIT    <<======================

I made a mistake and said this was for an `Activity` but it's not. I am calling the `onDestroy` of a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and unfortunately there is no `onPause` method to override there...

Comment: Use apply instead of commit. See here for explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference

Comment: Take a look at the edit and see if it helps ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29), don't rely on the `onDestroy()` method to persist your data. Use [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) instead.

> **Note:** do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data!
>
> For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, **those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here**. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running.
>
> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

Also, you could try to use the method [`apply()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) instead of [`commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) on your `SharedPreferences.Editor` because it saves your data faster, asynchronously, and there's no return value to handle at all.

---

**EDIT:** Ok, so you're using a `Service`. Problem is, their lifetime can outlast an `Activity` life by far, as they keep running in the background. So the `onDestroy()` of your service can take a very long time before it gets called, even if you close your app with the back button.

I'm not sure how your app is supposed to work, but I can suggest a few things.

1. If you want to work on your `SharedPreferences` when the user closes the app, move that method to an `Activity` or;
2. Inside the `Activity#onPause()` you can destroy the `Service` using the [`stopService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) method. (See example below).
3. If your `Service` is supposed to do some work and if after this work is done it should modify the `SharedPreferences`, you could try to use an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), because once this kind of Service finishes its job, it'll destroy itself. But take note, only one `IntentService` can run at a time! It runs on a FIFO queue.
4. If you don't want to use an `IntentService`, you could also call [`stopSelf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf()) from within your regular `Service` to stop it and destroy it.

**Example on finishing a `Service`**:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
}
```

More info about `IntentService` on [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183).
More info on a `Service` lifecycle on [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle).

Comment: That is a very good suggestion but unfortunately doesn't work for me. There is no `onPause()` in my case because this is not an `Activity`.  I made a mistake.  This is a `Service` and for `Service`, there is only `onCreate`, `onStart` and `onDestroy` methods... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Well, take a look at the edit then. It might help. @th3pat3l

Answer (score 2):

`onDestroy` in `Service` can be reached by explicitly calling `stopService()` method.

Although you want to clear Shared Preferences in the Service, that's really not reliable. I'm sure there would be an `Activity` that starts the `Service`.

I'd make a method in that `Activity`, like this.

```
 private void stopService() {
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
 }
```

and whenever you want to actually kill the app, you can call along with the `stopService(..)` call like..

```
private void stopService() {
    clearPref();
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
}

private void clearPref() {
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();  // where editor is an Editor for Shared Preferences
    editor.commit();
}
```

For Service, you need to think about multiple scenarios of the life cycle of the app. It's often hard to think of situations, but I'm sure you will be able to figure out. Good luck!