# Check boolean on every app start

Tags: android

I want to check, if a boolean is true, on every app start. So when the boolean is false, the user should be redirected to a certain activity. I do this call in my start activity. But when the user enters the app via notification or direct activity start, this is not called.

I tried to do that in my Applications class, but since I can't redirect users to activities there, this does not work and I don't want to add this call to every activity.

How can I check, if a user is logged in no matter, which activity is started?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23919377/6507689

Comment: take a look at shared preference might be helpful

Comment: Yes I'm aware of them, but I need the place, where I can check them. As said, I tried it in the application class, but I can't start an activity from there

Comment: Only if the app is active, right? So if the app isn't open it should not check?

Comment: Only when the app is started

Comment: Check the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068148/android-sharedprefrences-get-null-when-app-or-phone-restart/38068498#38068498 link

Comment: Loading data via shared preference does work good for me, but I don't know, where I should call it, so it's 100% called on every app start, no matter which entry point the user takes.

Comment: Shared Preferences clears its data if the app crashes or is forced to stop.

Comment: I added an answer @Zoker

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look and try it :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a BaseActivity and extend all your activities with this base activity. Then put your boolean checking code in that base activity. No matter from which activity your app starts if all your activities and extending this base activity it will get called. It will look something like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // check your boolean here and act accordingly

    }

}
```

Then extend all your activities with this one.