# SharedPreference not updated after commit()

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I know this question already have tons of answer in SO but I haven't found the answer to my problem.

Here is my code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.clear();

//Adding values to editor
editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
editor.putString(Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF, phoneNo);
Log.d("debug", "config "+Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF);
Log.d("debug", "config "+phoneNo);

//Saving values to editor
editor.apply();
editor.commit();
```

What I understand is, `editor.putString(Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF, phoneNo)` means save the value of `phoneNo` into `PHONE_SHARED_PREF`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

But when in Log, `Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF` printed the default value, instead of the new value assigned in `phoneNo`. That's mean the value of `phoneNo` not correctly saved, no?

Can someone explain to me what's wrong with my code? :/

Comment: `commit()` and `apply()` are the same, with the latter not returning a boolean value. Remove either and try again. You can get the value using `editor.getString(Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF, "")`. The 2nd param is returned if the key does not exists.

Comment: Sorry, try `sharedPreferences.getString(...)`.

Comment: it returns nothing (2nd param)

Comment: If that's the case, it means the preference doesn't exists. Use the `getAll()` method to check if your preference contains the keys and values you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.clear();

//Adding values to editor
editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true)
      .putString(Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF, phoneNo)
      .commit(); // returns true if successfully saved. 

Log.d("debug", "config " + sharedPreferences.getString(Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF, "");
```

Try the above.

Comment: this one works! thanks! mind to explain a little bit? still new in shared preference :)

Comment: Everything you've done in your code seems correct, except the part where you include `apply()` and `commit()`. Essentially, you'll only need to use either one, not both. You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Please accept the answer if possible, it would be of help to others in the future if they're looking for similar help. :]

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true).commit();
sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF, phoneNo).commit();
```