# SharedPreferences doesn't seem to save the variables

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I have a class that implements the SharedPreferences but whenever I try to save the data or get the data it does not seem to do it.

```
public class SharedPreferenceManager {

public SharedPreferenceManager() {
    super();
}

public static final String FILENAME = "PREFERENCES_FILE";

public static void saveData(Context context, String key, String data)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, data);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String getData(Context context, String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String data = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
    return data;
}

public static void removeData(Context context, String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.remove(key);

}
}
```

This is where I save the Data:

```
public class CreateUserActivity extends Activity {
EditText txtName, txtEmail, txtPassword;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
private String token;
private SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager;

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_user_activity);
    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginName);
    txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    sharedPreferenceManager = new SharedPreferenceManager();
}

public void checkCreateUser(View view) throws JSONException {
    String name = txtName.getText().toString();
    String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
    String token = getToken();

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.login_remember_checkbox);
    if (name.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0 && email.trim().length() > 0) {
        JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject();
        userObj.put("name", name);
        userObj.put("email", email);
        userObj.put("password", password);
        String jsonDocument = userObj.toString();
        PostUserTask put = new PostUserTask();
        put.execute("http://api.evang.dk/v2/users", jsonDocument);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            sharedPreferenceManager.saveData(CreateUserActivity.this, "USERNAME", name);
            sharedPreferenceManager.saveData(CreateUserActivity.this, "EMAIL", email);
            sharedPreferenceManager.saveData(CreateUserActivity.this, "PASSWORD", password);
            sharedPreferenceManager.saveData(CreateUserActivity.this, "TOKEN", token);
        } else {
            sharedPreferenceManager.removeData(CreateUserActivity.this, "USERNAME");
            sharedPreferenceManager.removeData(CreateUserActivity.this, "EMAIL");
            sharedPreferenceManager.removeData(CreateUserActivity.this, "PASSWORD");
            sharedPreferenceManager.removeData(CreateUserActivity.this, "TOKEN");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert.showAlertDialog(CreateUserActivity.this, "Login failed!", "Please enter name, username and password", false);
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), UserActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("SESSIONID", token);
    i.putExtra("NAMEID", name);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And where I read the data of the SharedPreferences:

```
EditText userNameTxt, passwordTxt, emailTxt;
SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager;
String token;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    userNameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameLogin);
    passwordTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
    emailTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
    sharedPreferenceManager = new SharedPreferenceManager();
    String userName = sharedPreferenceManager.getData(getBaseContext(), "USERNAME");
    String email = sharedPreferenceManager.getData(getBaseContext(), "EMAIL");
    String password = sharedPreferenceManager.getData(getBaseContext(), "PASSWORD");
    token = sharedPreferenceManager.getData(getBaseContext(), "TOKEN");
    if(userName != null && email != null && password != null && token != null)
    {
        userNameTxt.setText(userName);
        emailTxt.setText(email);
        passwordTxt.setText(password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between commit() and apply() in Shared Preference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference)

Comment: How are you using this class? Where and when are you reading and writing data from it?

Comment: @clownba0t Question was edited for more information.

Comment: Thanks! So just to confirm, the issue is that you're logging in with the "remember me" button checked, but the data isn't being saved to `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: @clownba0t Yes that is correct

Comment: As an aside, you should call `editor.apply();` after `editor.remove();` in your `removeData` method.

Comment: Have you tried adding logging to each of the methods in your `SharedPreferenceManager` class and doing another user creation action with the "remember me" checkbox checked? That way you could see which, if any, of the methods are being called.

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason you're using `getBaseContext()` in your calls where you read the data? Your `Activity` is already a context, so you can just pass `this` instead.

Comment: Okay! I found the culprit! The problem is that my token variable is set to null for some reason. And since i have an if statement that says if it's not null to set the Edit Texts, it will never be able to set them.

Comment: Now, I have another problem. It only saves the username :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- since in `saveData(...)`, you use `editor.apply()` and not `editor.commit()`, it's possible your data hasn't been written to file before you're reading it. (`editor.apply()` is asynchronous and doesn't write changes to disk immediately unlike `editor.commit()`)

Try using `editor.commit()` instead, like this:

```
public static void saveData(Context context, String key, String data)
{
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, data);
editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is necessarily correct. The documentation for `SharedPreferences` states that "For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share." (provided those clients are within the same process). Also, although `apply` is considered asynchronous, it's only the writing of the changes to disk that is asynchronous. As per the documentation, "..., apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk ...".

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is is implemented with **Singleton**, so you can't create new instances of it.. all of the references in this code point to the same instance.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, then it's probably some other issue then.