# Android - Sharedpreferences does not retrieving values When Tap on timepicker dialog Button

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog, timepicker

I'm trying to build application which get time from timepicker dialog and store time in sharedpreferences and retrieve those value from sharedpreferences to store into other variable **testhour** and **testminutes**. I'm trying to store values when user tap on **Set** Button of timePicker Dialog.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button setTime;
    public int testhour=14;
    public int testminute=25;
    public String hourx,minutex;

    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        setTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                final int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putString("hours", String.valueOf(selectedHour));
                        editor.putString("minute", String.valueOf(selectedMinute));
                        editor.apply();

                    }

                }, hour, minute, true);
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();
                mTimePicker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                        {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        hourx = prefs.getString("hours", null);//"No name defined" is the default value.
        minutex = prefs.getString("minute", null);
        testhour = Integer.parseInt(hourx);
        testminute = Integer.parseInt(minutex);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time Has Been Set for "+ testhour + ": "+testminute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

But it's not working.. it's not storing values in testhours and testminute when I tap on set Button of timePicker dialog.

Comment: use `.commit()` instead of `.apply()` for the `editor` method. See [commit vs apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference) question that was asked previously.

Comment: save works fine problem when retrieving data