# SharedPreferences not saving in onPause method

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, onpause

I save the state of a boolean in onPause method. I have tried using both editor.apply() and editor.commit() but still the values are not saved.
Here is the onPause method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.clear(); //I have tried omitting it
            editor.putBoolean(MUTE_TAG,mute);
            editor.apply(); // I tried editor.commit() but with no effect
            boolean mute1 = preferences.getBoolean(MUTE_TAG,false);
            Log.d(TAG,"Values:\n"+ "mute1 " + mute1 + " mute);
            super.onPause();
        }
```

Note: When I try to access the value from the SharedPreferences again from different activity, it isn't updated. Here is the setup code

```
public static boolean mute;
public static final String PREFS = "prefs";
    init(Context context) {
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
    mute = preferences.getBoolean(MUTE_TAG,false);
        }

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d(TAG,"MUTE PRESSED");
            mute = isChecked;
            break;
}
```

Comment: No, `preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
        mute = preferences.getBoolean(MUTE_TAG,false);`

Comment: remove clear and call super.onPause() at the beginning. if you use apply() or commit() does not matter in your case.

Comment: Pls, show me how you retrieve the preferences Object.

Comment: `public static void init(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);` I want the mute field to be static and call the init from Application class to have the mute which is public static field accesible to all classes

Comment: Look at the edited question

Answer (score 0):

What about after saving? Does the logcat show the **current/expected value?**

Here is what has worked for me:

Before : `private boolean mute = true;` but after sending the app to background. the result showed it true. While the default value is false;

**COPIED YOUR CODE AS-IS**

**ONLY PROBLEM:** Unclosed string literal

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        mute = !mute ;
        Log.d(TAG, "UPDATED MUTE VALUE :: " + mute);

        editor.clear(); //I have tried omitting it
        editor.putBoolean(MUTE_TAG,mute);
        editor.apply(); // I tried editor.commit() but with no effect
        boolean mute1 = preferences.getBoolean(MUTE_TAG,false);
        Log.d(TAG,"Values:\n"+ "mute:  " + mute1 + " mute");
        super.onPause();
    }
```

**SOLUTION #2**

It is connected to this [What's the difference between commit() and apply() in Shared Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference) . Try using commit again, commit will block `super.onPause` from executing thus making sure it saves

**SOLUTION #3**

Your activities are calling `onPause` after `onCreate` thus saving back the **default** `mute` value. Therefore, Create a class & add STATIC PUBLIC /PUBLIC STATIC variables that will store the mute value & **only save it when an activity is being destroyed**. This static variable will not change it's value across activities

Comment: Is mute always returning **false**? If so, most likey onPause is being called other times. Could you save the mute status in the method `onCheckedChanged`? This might be a better strategy, there will be little if any performance effect of this

Comment: It looks to be somewhat random. Sometimes, it is reversed, other times it isn't.

Comment: Try saving the value in `onCheckedChanged`. The activity(s) might be calling onPause when the activity(s) starts

Comment: Turns out that in the preferences.xml file, only 2 preferences are being saved at one time. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I have 4 switches which are implemented in that way and only the state of two of them are getting saved, no matter how many times I switch them or restart the activity and yes they all have different onCheckedChangeListeners. Here is an [image](https://vgy.me/197zHN.png) of what I mentioned

Comment: Do you have a repository on Github so that I can see all the code that's not working as expected?

Comment: **MUTE_TAG, TTS_TAG, COUNTDOWN_TAG, LOG_TAG** all have the same tag name. It should be different for each