# Mediaplayers get muted/unmuted too late

Tags: java, android, audio, checkbox, android-mediaplayer

I have set up a `Checkbox`, Now if it is unchecked the `mediaplayers` should **Immediately be unmuted** and when checked **immediately muted**, now the problem is when I check/uncheck the checkbox, the sound will not be muted immediately but as recently I restart the activity... How can I solve this problem?

**Main code of  the program:**

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

private TextView mScoreView;
private TextView mQuestionView;
private Button mButtonChoice1;
private Button mButtonChoice2;
private Button mButtonChoice3;
private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionNumber = 0;
Dialog dialog;
Dialog dialog2;
TextView closeButton;
TextView closeButton2;
CheckBox checkBoxmp;
private MediaPlayer mp, mp2;

SharedPreferences mypref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);


    //Dialog 1
    createDialog();
    Button dialogButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //end Dialog 1

    //Dialog 2
    createDialog2();
    Button dialogButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn2);
    dialogButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog2.show();

        }
    });


    closeButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog2.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //end Dialog 2

    SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();

    checkBoxmp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            editor.putBoolean("playSounds", !isChecked);
            editor.commit();
            if (null != mp && null != mp2) {
                if (!isChecked) {
                    mp.setVolume(1, 1);
                    mp2.setVolume(1, 1);
                } else {
                    mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                    mp2.setVolume(0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    final boolean playSounds = mypref.getBoolean("playSounds", false);
    checkBoxmp.setChecked(!playSounds);

    TextView shareTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share);
    shareTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            myIntent.setType("text/plain");
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello!");
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My highscore in Quizzi is very high! I bet you can't beat me except you are cleverer than me. Download the app now! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=amapps.impossiblequiz");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with:"));
        }
    });

    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();

    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action));
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"

    ((NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1)).setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_stats:
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about:
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu3.class));
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
    mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);

    final List<Button> choices = new ArrayList<>();
    choices.add(mButtonChoice1);
    choices.add(mButtonChoice2);
    choices.add(mButtonChoice3);

    updateQuestion();


    //Code of the mediaplayer begins:

    for (final Button choice : choices) {
        choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (choice.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                    try {
                        mp = new MediaPlayer();
                        if (playSounds) {
                            mp.setVolume(1, 1);
                        } else {
                            mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                        }

                        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                        afd = getAssets().openFd("sample.mp3");
                        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        mp.prepare();

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.release();
                        }
                    });
                    mp.start();
                    updateScore();
                    updateQuestion();
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    try {
                        mp2 = new MediaPlayer();
                        if (playSounds) {
                            mp2.setVolume(1, 1);
                        } else {
                            mp2.setVolume(0, 0);
                        }
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                        afd = getAssets().openFd("wrong.mp3");
                        mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        mp2.prepare();

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.release();
                        }
                    });
                    mp2.start();

                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


//End mediaplayer main code
private void updateQuestion() {
    if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));
        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber++);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
        intent.putExtra("score", mScore);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void updateScore() {
    mScoreView.setText(String.valueOf(++mScore));

    SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);

    if (mScore > highScore) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore", mScore);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Tutorial");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu1_1);
    closeButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeTXT);
}


private void createDialog2() {
    dialog2 = new Dialog(this);
    dialog2.setTitle("Settings");
    dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu1_2);
    closeButton2 = (TextView) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.closeTXT2);
    checkBoxmp = (CheckBox) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.ckeckBox);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Now it's look like all should to work.

Comment: I have already sir

Answer (score 2):

Try Changing `editor.commit` to `editor.apply` as `.commit` blocks the UI while writing the shared preference to the disk and waits until the write is finished for the next line of code to execute where as `.apply` sends the shared preference writing to a worker thread thus executing the next line of code instantaneously as @Pavel has mentioned. [look here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5960732/4944007) and [this is the official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply())

Answer (score 0):

`final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();`
try to move this string into `onCheckChanged()`
and also use `editor.apply()` instead of `editor.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

try editing in shared preference within onCheckChanged :

```
//end Dialog 2

    SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    checkBoxmp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("playSounds", !isChecked);
            editor.commit();
            if (null != mp && null != mp2) {
                if (!isChecked) {
                    mp.setVolume(1, 1);
                    mp2.setVolume(1, 1);
                } else {
                    mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                    mp2.setVolume(0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use media Player onPrepared listener and start media player only once the data if pre fetched from the server.

```
 mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
       }
 });
```

2.Replace this by below line of code as you have already have declared SharedPreferences as member variable.Maintain only one instance of SharedPreference.

```
SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
```

with

```
mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

3.Replace editor.commit() with editor.apply()

editor.commit() waits until the write is finished for the next line and it blocks the UI while writing the shared preferences but editor.apply() writes into the disk by creating a worker thread.