# Access Shared Preference from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

Get SharedPreference values from activity to a fragment

Shared Pref code in activty

```
val editor =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext).edit()
                        editor.putString("Token", addToken)
                        editor.putString("isNew", 
  response.body()!!.isNew)
                        editor.putString("ccid", 
  response.body()!!.ccId)
                        editor.putString("email", email)
 editor.apply()
```

SharedPref Code in Fragment

```
   val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    token = sharedPreferences.getString("Token", "")
    ccID = sharedPreferences.getString("ccid", "")
```

How to retrieve the values of shared Preference in a fragment from an Activity.Currently i'm not able to access the token from activity to fragment

Comment: have you done this editor.apply() after putString()?

Comment: yes .. Have done editor.apply()

Comment: Try doing this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/8101634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `context` in your `Fragment` what I did is this :

```
private val mContext by lazy {
        this@YourFragment.context
}
```

And then you can use `mContext` as a `Context`.

And instead of passing `applicationcontext`in your `Activity` send `this` instead.

```
val editor =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **getActivity()** instaed of **context** in Fragment

`val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());`

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `commit()` method of editor?

See details:
[What's the difference between commit() and apply() in Shared Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference)