# Getting previous values from Sharedpreferences in android non activity class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I would like to read data from shared preferences in android non activity class.

When I was try to read data from shared preferences in non activity class, it will return previous values.

**MyActivity class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 SharedPreferences preferences;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final APIClient client = new APIClient(this);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("loginData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("ip",ipAddress);
        editor.putString("username",uname);
        editor.putString("pwd",pwd);
        editor.apply();
        client.start();
     }
}
```

**My non activity class:**

public class APIClient {

```
 public Context mcontext;
 public APIClient(Context context) {
        mcontext = context;
    }
    public void start(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
        mcontext.getSharedPreferences("loginData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String data = sharedPreferences.getString("ip","");
        uname = sharedPreferences.getString("username","");
        pwd = sharedPreferences.getString("pwd","");
        Log.d("*****","userName ="+uname+"\n"+pwd);
        Toast.makeText(mcontext,"user name ="+uname+"\n"+"pwd="+pwd,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me how to read data immediately when data update from activity class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Answer (score 1):

Your APIClent shouldn't know about SharedPreferences, instead give it the values it needs at the call site:

```
final String data = sharedPreferences.getString("ip","");
final String uname = sharedPreferences.getString("username","");
final String pwd = sharedPreferences.getString("pwd","");

client.start(data, uname, pwd);
```

Api Class:

```
public void start(String data, String uname, String pwd){
    // call api...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for JakeB your suggestions. It's working fine. Actually here i want build and save url dynamically by using the shared preferences.

Comment: You should build the URL before hand, look at Uri.Builder

Answer (score 0):

Try `editor.commit()` instead of `editor.apply()` .

As it might be the case that the changes are still not saved while u are trying to access the value.

For more info on `commit vs apply` refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5960743/7972699) .

Better solution will be not to send context inside and update values when needed.Using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener#onSharedPreferenceChanged(android.content.SharedPreferences,%20java.lang.String)) *(As pointed by @JakeB)*