# Android SharedPreferences.Editor apply takes too long

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have the following PreferenceActivity

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {

Preference server;
EditTextPreference editServer;
ProgressDialog mDialog;
Handler handler;
Preference bgColor;
EditTextPreference editbgColor;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    server = findPreference("webservice");
    editServer = (EditTextPreference)server;
    bgColor = findPreference("bgColorOption");
    editbgColor = (EditTextPreference)bgColor;

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    saveSettings();
}

private void saveSettings() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();  
    editor.putString("Servidor", String.valueOf(editServer.getText().toString()));
    editor.putString("bgCor",String.valueOf(editbgColor.getText().toString()));
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

and my settings.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Sistema"> 

<EditTextPreference
    android:dialogMessage="@string/pref_webservice"
    android:defaultValue="http://"
    android:title="@string/pref_webservice"
    android:key="webservice"/> 

</PreferenceCategory> 

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Aparencia"> 
<EditTextPreference
    android:dialogMessage="@string/BackgroundColorOption"
    android:defaultValue="#ffffff"
    android:title="@string/BackgroundColorOption"
    android:key="bgColorOption" /> 
 </PreferenceCategory>
```

My issue is, when i go back from my settings activity i do the saveSettings and return to the main activity, and on my main activity onResume function i apply my new settings, but they dont apply immediatly, if i go on settings a second time and back again , then it does. I belive its because my editor.apply(); takes too long? any way to speed it up?

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    String server = settings.getString("servidor", "xxx");
    String bgColor = settings.getString("bgCor", "#000000");        
    mDialog.setMessage("A Actualizar...");
    thread.setServer(server);
    int cor = Color.parseColor(bgColor);
    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(cor);
}
```

Comment: use `commit()` instead of `apply()`

Comment: Consider moving the loading / storing of settings to an asynchronous task as disk access on the main thread is a anti-pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4371883/233048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you save your `SharedPreferences` inside `OnStop`. Try to move it to the `OnPause`.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
saveSettings();
}
```

Notion from the Android reference:

> protected void onStop ()
>
> [...]
>
> Note that this method may never be called, in low memory situations
>   where the system does not have enough memory to keep your activity's
>   process running after its onPause() method is called.