# Are shared preferences stored in memory during runtime?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Are shared preferences in Android always read at startup and stored in memory during runtime? If not, are there more efficient ways to read preferences than this?

```
settings = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsFile", 0);
int answer = settings.getInt("ULTIMATE_QUESTION", 42);
```

Comment: Yes, they are stored in memory (via Linux / Android disk read cache), and no, that is the most efficient way to read them.

Comment: Then what should be the preferred way of reading the preferences?

Comment: The way you have in your question, as the API does not offer anything else.

Comment: Interesting related information on [this answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371883/383414)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Are shared preferences in Android always read at startup and stored in memory during runtime**

Simply Yes till user doesn't clear it manually from setting.

**are there more efficient ways to read preferences than this**

As JonasCz said in comments.. this is the most common and developer friendly way till now.