# Other thread to read and write sharedPreferences

Tags: android, multithreading, io

I really have to use another thread to read and write a `sharedPreferences` file?

I'm storing an `integer array` in `sharedPreferences` file, I convert it in string to store there, ok, this array corresponds to the itens of a gridView, then I have to read it on `onCreate()` and write it on `onDestroy()`, the problem is I'm calling an `asyncTask` on onCreate() and this is causing a lot of problems... the main one is that the onCreate() is been called many times (every time that other activity came in front mine, it is destroyed and restarted...), I found out in here that a kind bug occurs when other thead is called on onCreate(), then I had to save some things on `onSaveInstanceState()`, but this only resolved my problem in part. I already tested do not use other thread and read and write the file directly on UI thread, and this worked nicely, but I always heard I have to use other thread to any kind of `I/O`... then I'm in doubt...

After all, I can or I can't read and write a sharedPreferences file without call other thread?

Thx

Comment: You can read/write to SharedPreferences without problems in UI thread if its small. It's all cached and done async in background. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4371883/1626594 for a clearer explanation.

Comment: Really thx @Francisco M.